# How to remove duplicates in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I couldn't find a transformer to remove duplicated entries in the scikit-learn, like drop_duplicates in pandas.

- How can I deal with this problem?
- Should I write a [custom transformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#custom-transformers)? if yes, how? I would appreciate it if you could help me in this regard.
- Which one is faster, using pandas or sciki-learn?

Best regards,

Comment: why do you want to use sklearn for removing duplicates - when you can do it in dataframe itself by using pandas functions. question is not clear

Comment: What's the context in which you would use this transformer? Part of a Pipeline object? You can use FunctionTransformer wrapping pandas drop_duplicates as a first attempt.

Comment: Exactly, part of a Pipeline, so you mean 'transformer = FunctionTransformer(pd.drop_duplicates())' right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better, simpler and faster to drop duplicates first and foremost before any pipeline work so the data doesn't get mixed up in the pipeline, and you can split it early using the `train_test_split`. Simply use:

`df_dropped = df.drop_duplicates()`